# Spring Security "Remember Me" cookie gets deleted on browser closed event

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security

I've followed Spring Security's instructions and managed to authenticate my users using JDBC in a Spring Boot project with "**Remember Me**" feature enabled (and setAlwaysRemember(true)). The "**Remember Me**" **cookie** gets created in the client's browser and the Token gets inserted into the "**presistent_logins**" table without fail.
But here comes the dilemma, When the client closes the browser, the "**Remember Me**" cookie gets removed automatically, which somehow makes all my effort effectless.
what would be the point of having Remember Me feature, if the cookie which is an essential requirement, gets removed on every browser closed event. Therefore, the user has to do the login all over again.
Here is a picture that shows the remember me cookie has been created after a successful login.

Do I have to take some special measures to make sure that the cookie gets preserved in the browser?

Chrome >>
[image]

Firefox >>

[image]

Comment: The browser isn't in incognito mode and/or configured to automatically delete cookies on exit?

Comment: No, I'm sure about that. and the other cookies (for other web apps and websites for example) are being stored and accessible even after the browser restart.
its only Remember Me cookie (from Spring Security) which is being deleted after the browser get closed.

Comment: What browser do you use? Did you try it with a different browser?

Comment: Initially, I've tested with Chrome. but then I checked the same in Firefox as well.
The results are the same. the cookie gets created upon successful login, but when I close the browser and reopen it again, it's gone.

Comment: @Majid Did you check the config of Chrome and Firefox. Both have an option to delete cookies by closing the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the browser who is clearing the `remember-me` cookie. It's your spring app which tells the browser to clear that cookie (by giving an old expiry time).

So why does spring do that?

Because internally spring is throwing `BadCredentialsException`. You should debug `RememberMeAuthenticationProvider` class to make sure why it's throwing that exception.

In my case, the remember-me `secret key` was different than the one I used in my `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` class.

So please debug your application to find out the root cause of it...

Comment: Yes!  Thank you, in my case, after debug with spring sec source (did not work) but then set spring sec to trace debug level, I saw that my key was not matching in my rememeber me cookie: ... o.s.s.w.a.r.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as AuthenticationManager rejected Authentication returned by RememberMeServices: ...invalidating remember-me token
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: The presented RememberMeAuthenticationToken does not contain the expected key

Answer (score 0):

Finally had to use normal mode of Remember Me feature (not DB persistence mode) in order to have this working. :(
When I use DB to persist session information, upon closing the browser, the "remember-me" session vanishes somehow!